# Use of SQL Server Management Objects in an application

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

A developer on my current project has used Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo within the code of our development to build tables programmatically.

To me this seems like a bad idea.

Is it?

Comment: What aspect seems a "bad idea" to you? Taking a dependency on `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`? Creating tables through it rather than through SQL script? both? Something else?

Comment: It's the use of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo running on an application server. This dll seems to be designed for writing management applications as opposed to using it for standard database manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I thing being or not being a bad idea for that matter depends on the environment under which the application will be run or deployed or what the application is required to do.

SMO makes it easy to perform database administration operations in .NET code. While all of those admin tasks can be performed with T-SQL directly on a database or through the SQL Server Management Studio, being able to use SMO offers broad flexibility to include these types of operations in .NET applications.

In fact, SQL Server Management Studio relies on SMO for most of its management tasks.
I did find an article demonstrating what can be done with SMO here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163409.aspx